# Why do traceroutes start with the same path?

Tags: networking, routing, terminal, traceroute

I'm curious as to why all traceroutes start with the same path. For example, if I want to do a traceroute from my current location to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and another one to [www.bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk), the first few hops(4 for me) of the traceroute are the exact same for both traceroutes. I'm wondering why is this the case?

Comment: In most cases there's only one preferred route for traffic to take and your traffic will always need to take that route, before it can reach an internet exchange or (border) router where it will make sense to make different routing decisions. A bit like how when navigating from most residences in the suburbs (with cul-de-sacs and one-way streets) there will be only  one route you can take to leave that suburb.  And only once you're leaving that suburb there will  be a crossroads  where certain destinations require you to go in another direction than others.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to be able to see the actual traceroute, but:

Traceroute shows a 'hop' for each individual router. The 1st hop is the same because that's usually *your* own home router; the 2nd hop is the same because it's your router's default gateway.

That leaves only two more hops out of the original four. They might still belong to your own ISP, e.g. first going to the same central office, then to the same node at a nearby IX.

Second, many ISPs **only have** a few paths to the Internet anyway (depending on how large the ISP is). A small company might only have 1 upstream link in total, a larger one might have connections to 3 carriers – not hundreds. A few sites will be reachable through specific peerings, but the huge majority will go through the same few routes.

(It's the carriers that have hundreds of connections, and that's where the paths really start diverging.)

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense! Thanks!